# Solving $ \int \sqrt{4\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) } dx $ without an elliptical integral

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Solving:

$$
\int \sqrt{4\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) }   dx
$$

I have used calculators attempt this problem, but they all use the elliptical integral of the second parameter. My goal is to somehow solve this without using it.

Trying some substitutions:

$u = \sin^2(x)$, $\frac{du}{2\cos(x)\sin(x)} = dx$

$\sin(x)$ = $\sqrt{u}$, $\cos(x)$ = $\sqrt{1-u}$,

$$
\int  \frac{\sqrt{3u + 1 }}{2(\sqrt{1-u})\sqrt{u}}  du =
$$

$$
\int  \frac{\sqrt{3u + 1 }}{2\sqrt{u-u^2 } }  du = 
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2} \int  \frac{\sqrt{3u + 1 }}{\sqrt{u-u^2 } }  du  
$$

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: $\cos x\neq 1-u^2.$ $\cos x=\sqrt{1-u}.$

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasAndrews , I'll revise it

Comment: What makes you think it's possible to find this antiderivative without elliptic integrals? They were introduced for a reason, you know...

Comment: You don’t want an answer in terms of elliptic integrals, but you don’t specify what alternatives you’d accept. I could give you an answer in terms of hypergeometric functions, but it would still be equivalent to an elliptic integral even though it has a different name.